# Что означает нижнее подчеркивание в конце reduce?

Tags: javascript

Разбираю код

```js
const data = [
    {
      continent_name: "Asia",
      country_name: "Iran",
      subdivision_1_name: "Chaharmahal and Bakhtiari Province",
      city_name: "Lir Abi"
    },
    {
      continent_name: "Europe",
      country_name: "Cyprus",
      subdivision_1_name: "Ammochostos",
      city_name: "Protaras"
    },
    {
      continent_name: "Asia",
      country_name: "Iran",
      subdivision_1_name: "West Azerbaijan Province",
      city_name: "Post"
    },
    {
      continent_name: "Africa",
      country_name: "Somalia",
      subdivision_1_name: "Bakool",
      city_name: "Oddur"
    }
  ],
  
  keys = ["continent_name", "country_name", "subdivision_1_name", "city_name"],
  
  result = data.reduce(
    (r, o) => {
      keys.reduce(function (q, k) {
        const label = o[k];
        if (!q[label]) q._.push({ label, children: (q[label] = { _: [] })._ });
        return q[label];
      }, r);
      return r;
    },
    { _: [] }
  )._;
```

Как работает вот это последняя строка  `)._;`?

Если он возвращает `[]` вот этот массив, то почему мой код не работает?

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
const a = numbers.reduce((a, c) => a._ += c, { _: 5 })._;
```

Получаю ошибку

*Cannot create property '_' on number '6'*

Comment: возвращать надо потому что `a`, а не вот это вот, что у вас написано. зы: ошибки с `_` не наблюдаю

Comment: подчеркивание в данном случае, просто имя свойства.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведу описание того насколько я понял текущую логику.

**TD;DR**  Вкратце `_` - это генерируемый в редюсере ключ, который заполняется всеми элементами изначального массива, т.е. в свою очередь подвергаются иерархичному вкложению исходя из массива `keys` и объединению схожих ключей. (В данном случае имеются не сами ключи, а их значения)

Так же доработал ваш пример кода, в данном случае нужно учесть что срелочная функция редюсера возвращает аккумулятор, но вы пытались вернуть число у которого нет свойства `_`. Все что я сделал - использовал [оператор запятая](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), чтобы вернуть именно аккумулятор, для того чтобы парсер не ругался я обернул результат стрелочной функции в скобки.

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
const a = numbers.reduce((a, c) => (a._ += c, a ), { _: 5 })._;
console.log(a)
```

**Подробнее:**

Мы видим что в качестве `начального результата`редюсера передается объект со свойством `_` которое равно пустому массиву в коде так:

```
  result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
      ...................
    }
    { _: [] } <------ начальный результат
  )
```

назовем это `RESULT`.

**Чем по итогу будет `_`.**

Для начала установим что он будет ключем `r` (аккумулятор), напомню это тот самый `{ _: [] }` или `RESULT`

Далее мы видим вложенный редюсер который в который через область видимости передается опять тот самый `r` или `RESULT`,
но уже под именем `q` в качестве начального значения аккумулятора.

```
  result = data.reduce((r, o) => { -----,
      keys.reduce(function (q, k)       |
      }, r);  <-------------------------`
      ........................
    },
    { _: [] }
  )._;
```

Этот внутренний редюсер отвечает за то чтобы преобразовать
элементы `data` в объекты. Массив `keys` служит правилом иерархии этого объекта. Каждый элемент `keys` будет вложен в предыдущий. Как упоминалось выше работа идет со значениями.

например: `"continent_name"` это  `текущийЭлементData['continent_name']`

Мы видим как заполняется `_`, примерно так:

`_.push(label, children:[])`

условие `if` проверяет если значение по ключу из `keys` (`label`) в `RESULT` отсутствует то в массив ключа `_` пушится  элемент, содержащий `label` и еще массив дочерних элементов:

`children: (q[label] = { _: [] })._`

*(слелдует отметить что тут `_` не то которое мы обсуждаем, более того его назначение мне не понятно, поэтому не заостряю на нем внимание, тем не менее, полагаю что вместо `_` тут больше бы подошло так же `children`)*

Что тут происходит, `q[label]` приравнивается `{ _: [] }` как известно операция присваивания возвращает результат присваивания таким образом это объект `{ _: [] }` из которого мы потом выбираем значение по ключу `_` что есть пустой массив.

Таким образом в условии `if` происходит сразу 2 вещи

- q._.push(...) вставка в ключ `_` в `RESULT`
- q[label]= .... присваивание ключу в `RESULT` по имени из значений `keys`

Встроенный редюсер возвращает `q[label]` т.е. вложенное свойство `q` а не сам `q` (напомню что `q` - это `r` таким образом происходит вкладывание свойств друг в друга.

**В итоге**

По ключам верхнего уровня `"continent_name"` формируются смерженные объекты с вложенностью друг в друга (вспоминаем `q[label]`) которые в свою очередь попадают в ключ верхнего уровня `_`, который изначально был пустым массивом.

Comment: Балдёж, спасибо огромное